# Is it possible to convert lists into table?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I'm totally new to python3, I am trying to create a basic program to collect information about my Airbnb's guests. I collected the datas in lists and now I'd need to create a table that shows the datas. Here is the code:

```
# program to collect information from the guests to pay the 

accomodation fees
n_guests = int(input("Quanti sono gli ospiti quest'oggi? "))
n = 1
name = []
surname = []
place_birth = []
date_birth = []
place_residence = []
citizenship = []
id_card = []
number_id = []
city_id = []
country_id = []
issue_id = []
notes = []

while n <= n_guests:
    print("Dati relativi al " + str(n) + "° ospite.")
    print("Nome: ")
    name.append(input())
    print("Cognome: ")
    surname.append(input())
    print("Luogo di nascita: ")
    place_birth.append(input())
    print("Data di nascita: ")
    date_birth.append(input())
    print("Luogo di residenza: ")
    place_residence.append(input())
    print("Cittadinanza: ")
    citizenship.append(input())
    print("Carta d'identità cartacea o elettronica?")
    id_card.append(input())
    print("Numero carta d'identità: ")
    number_id.append(input())
    print("Città che ha rilasciato il documento: ")
    city_id.append(input())
    print("Stato: ")
    country_id.append(input())
    print("Data di rilascio: ")
    issue_id.append(input())
    print("Scrivere qui eventuali rettifiche: ")
    notes.append(input())
    n = n+1

print("Caricamento effettuato con successo!")
```

any help?

Comment: Do you want to display the data as a table in the console or in the webpage?

Comment: I was thinking to create a table that can be printed or in a way that can match easily with excel. It is doable?

Answer (score 0):

use can use pandas library, which you can simply add and delete your data in CSV file.